# HTTP/2 connection error (PROTOCOL_ERROR): Request headers too long

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that should be able to show large string values (~20k chars).

In the past this value was rendered as a textarea value in a razor *.cshtml page. But when I displayed the webpage in firefox, the browser was not loading the page. (Don't have got further error description here)

I decided not to render the textarea value in the *.cshtml page anymore. Therefore I've added a script that loads the data via `$.get()` when the user clicks a button.

But I'm still unable to deal with the large values..!? Why is this? The large value is only treated on the server side - no transmission to the client! Or am I wrong?

I have turned now the log level (in *appsettings.Development.json*) to *debug*.

Now I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2ConnectionErrorException: HTTP/2 connection error (PROTOCOL_ERROR): Request headers too long.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.OnHeaderCore(Nullable`1 index, Boolean indexedValue, ReadOnlySpan`1 name, ReadOnlySpan`1 value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.OnStaticIndexedHeader(Int32 index, ReadOnlySpan`1 value)
   at System.Net.Http.HPack.HPackDecoder.ProcessHeaderValue(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, IHttpHeadersHandler handler)
   at System.Net.Http.HPack.HPackDecoder.ParseHeaderValue(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, Int32& currentIndex, IHttpHeadersHandler handler)
   at System.Net.Http.HPack.HPackDecoder.DecodeInternal(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, IHttpHeadersHandler handler)
   at System.Net.Http.HPack.HPackDecoder.Decode(ReadOnlySequence`1& data, Boolean endHeaders, IHttpHeadersHandler handler)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.DecodeHeadersAsync(Boolean endHeaders, ReadOnlySequence`1& payload)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.ProcessContinuationFrameAsync(ReadOnlySequence`1& payload)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.ProcessFrameAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, ReadOnlySequence`1& payload)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Comment: Please look at the problematic request through Firefox inspector (F12, network tab). What is the headers of request? What is the biggest header?

Comment: There is one large header in my (failed) request: `cookie`.
The header contains e.g. `.AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProviderC1` to `...C8`. Can this be the cause? But what does the client deal with _tempdata_?

Comment: This cookie uses for store [TempData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#tempdata). Do you store there a large amount of data?

Comment: Yes, sure: My `TempData` ist large. But as I have read, `TempData` is a server side construct!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using now `HttpContext.Session` instead of `TempData` in my controller. That's it..